# In VQ-VAE code what does this line of code signify?

Tags: variational-autoencoder

The VQ-VAE implimentation:https://colab.research.google.com/github/zalandoresearch/pytorch-vq-vae/blob/master/vq-vae.ipynb

```
quantized = inputs + (quantized - inputs).detach()
```

Why are we subtracting and adding input to quantized result?

Comment: Numerical stability.

Comment: @AbhishekVerma it would be really helpful if you could please explain this with a little detail....kind of a newbie here.

Answer (score 2):

This is to get the gradient to "skip" the quantization part.

The trick implements the red arrow in the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00937)'s diagram:

[image: VQ-VAE architecture, with red arrow signifying gradient skipping from quantized code vector to encoder output]

#### Simplified example: Rounding

Let's simplify this a bit and imagine we want to use rounding in our architecture:

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([1.1, 2.1], requires_grad=True)
y = 2*x
z = torch.round(y)
r = z.sum()
```

The graph (`torchviz.make_dot`) looks like this:

[image]

We can look at the output:

```
r 
# tensor(6., grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
```

All is looking good. However, when we try to compute the gradient, we get a tensor of zeroes:

```
r.backward()
x.grad
# tensor([0., 0.])
```

This makes sense: the rounding function has derivative zero almost everywhere:

[image]

However, it also means we cannot train our network.

To circumvent that, we could simply tell the gradient to skip the rounding network. To do that, we use [`detach`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.detach.html), a function that tells PyTorch to detach a vector from the computational graph.

```
x = torch.tensor([1.1, 2.1], requires_grad=True)
y = 2*x
z = torch.round(y)
z = y + (z - y).detach() # Detach everything between z and y, including z
r = z.sum()
```

We still get the same answer for $r$

```
r 
# tensor(6., grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
```

But we now also get reasonable gradients

```
r.backward()
x.grad
# tensor([2., 2.])
```

Thanks to the fact that the gradient now "skips" the rounding part:

[image]

#### Back to VQ-VAE

In VQ-VAE, we are replacing the output of the encoder (the `input` to the [vector quantization](http://www.mqasem.net/vectorquantization/vq.html) layer) with the **code vector**. In some sense, this similar to "rounding", only this time we're "rounding" the encoder's output to the nearest code vector.

[image]

We therefore run into the same problem. Here's what the authors say about it

> Note that there is no real gradient defined for [the quantization], however we approximate the gradient similar to the straight-through estimator and just copy gradients from decoder input $z_q(x)$ to encoder output $z_e(x)$

which is precisely what

```
quantized = inputs + (quantized - inputs).detach()
```

does in the notebook.